# Swift: conventions regarding masking optionals with a type alias?

Tags: swift, option-type, type-alias

Is there any convention about the usage of a type alias that masks an optional? For example, if I want to create a type alias for a verbose optional type such as `UnsafeMutablePointer<Bar>?`, I could do either of the following:

```
// Approach 1 - mask the optional in the type alias
typealias Foo = UnsafeMutablePointer<Bar>?

func bat(baz: Foo) { ... }

// Approach 2 - include the optional in the typealias usage where needed
typealias Foo = UnsafeMutablePointer<Bar>

func bat(baz: Foo?) { ... }
```

These approaches accomplish the same thing, though I would think the second is preferable because it seems more explicit that the function argument is optional.

Are there any situations where the first approach might be preferable, and are there any guidelines for/against such a usage?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to use a typealias for a function parameter that is optional but verbose, such as in my example (`UnsafeMutablePointer<Bar>?`). I am just wondering general pros/cons of masking an optional via a typealias, and if there are any conventions for this.

Comment: I think it depends on what makes the code clearer in you specific case. I don't think there can be a general answer.